# Create a Histogram in Excel with three different level

Tags: excel, histogram

Based on the picture that I have uploaded, how should I create it in Excel with three different level?

Thanks!

[image]

```
Grades  Bins    Frequency   Intervals
9   9   0   0-9
6   19  2   10-19
1   29  1   20-29
7   39      
5           
5           
2           
4           
6           
2
10
11          
15
18
20          
21
23
25  
26
27
29
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a histogram in Excel you would use **FREQUENCY**

This is no diferent in using something such as the groups for colours.
The difference is that you would use an **IF** statement referring to the group column.

```
=FREQUENCY(IF(GroupRange="GroupName",DataRange),BinRange)
```

So if your data was in B2:B40 and your group delimiter in C2:C40 and your bin sizes was in E2:E12 you would use a formula such as:

```
=FREQUENCY(IF($C$2:$C$40="B",$B$2:$B$40),$E$2:$E$12)
```

Then pop each group next to each other changing the "B" (or whatever) as you go.
Hopefully this will get oyu on the right track.

(note: with FREQUENCY you must array enter into all cells in line with the bin range... [ctrl]+[shift]+[enter])

Comment: I dont understand how to do it from the beginning to the end. I have learned the basic in this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asEuFvWGJDs

Comment: I have added the data on the top. Is ot ipssible that you can show it again based on the data above.

Comment: What would be your data ranges:
e.g Grades take up cells A1:Axx // Bins take up E1:E10 etc...
I canot see the colour group? What defiens the colour in your original image?

Comment: To make it easier, blue is "0-9", green is 10-19 and red is 20-29

Comment: So you would have 11 total colours and stack them based upon the frequency? 
This is not how a Histogram should work. But the results can be acheived.

Comment: For the data you have there you would usually have the Intervals as the x axis and the frequency as the y axis... there would be no colour.

Comment: Do you have another concrete example with sourcecode and result? It is easier to understand more about it. Same logic when you use jsfiddle but for excel.

Comment: Do you have the data to go with the image?
If you have the data to go with the image it can be done.
Any concrete examples I generate will be based upon my data and so likely more confusing than helpful.
Please upload data relevant to the image you provided at first.

Comment: I dont have the data to the picture. THe picture is taken från google's image search function